# Struct with explicit layout with LPWSTR and Structs

Tags: c#, .net, struct, pinvoke

For a pinvoke call I need to make a struct equivalent of say the following:

```
typedef struct _Somenativestruct {
 PCWSTR filename;
 DWORD count;
 DWORD anothercount;
 AnEnumWithByteSize info;
 union {
     Structwithoneintfield Progress;
     Anotherstructwithoneintfield Result;
 };
} Somenativestruct , *PSomenativestruct ;
```

Since it has one union in the struct I have to  make it layout.explicit but the issue is what is the offset I will do for the filename which is PCWSTR.
Since its a 32 bit pointer can I give an offset of 4? So is the following correct?

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public struct Mynet40struct
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        private [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string filename;
        [FieldOffset(4)]
        private int count;
        [FieldOffset(8)]
        private int anothercount;
        [FieldOffset(12)]
        AnEnumWithByteSize info;
        [FieldOffset(13)]
        StructWithOneIntField progress;
        [FieldOffset(13)]
        AnotherStructWithOneIntField result;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

It may be 8 bytes on 64-bit.

Make an explicit struct just for the union, and add it as a member of Mynet40struct which stays LayoutKind.Sequential.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few issues here that are worth considering.

First of all, you have assumed a packed layout. Perhaps the native struct really is packed but that would be unusual. It's normal for structs to be aligned.  Unless the native declaration contains a `#pragma pack` directive your struct will be aligned.

Secondly, pointers are different sizes for 32 and 64 bit targets and so your use of explicit will only be able to work for one target. The way to deal with that is to use explicit layout for the union only. That's the best way to handle unions.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct Mynet40union
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    StructWithOneIntField progress;
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    AnotherStructWithOneIntField result;
}
```

And then use this union in your struct.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct Mynet40struct
{
    string filename;
    int count;
    int anothercount;
    AnEnumWithByteSize info;
    Mynet40union progressOrResult;
}
```

If your struct really is packed then use the `Pack` parameter of the `StructLayout` attribute to specify that.